# What is this manga that has a guy with the power to make a transparent round bubble?

Tags: tanabata-no-kuni

I read it more than a year ago.

A guy first has the power to make a transparent round bubble like thing and everything that goes in it or touches it disappears. As the story goes on he can make a bigger bubble.

Then something shows up in the middle of his forehead - I think it was a third eye.

I don't know if I am mixing two manga together or not but I think later on the more power he uses he turns into an ET (alien) looking guy.

Comment: the bubble like power reminds me of 6 tails jinchuriki from naruto. no idea about that third eye.

Comment: No   Naruto  to bubble was black. It was from mouth.   One I mean comes from the guy hand.

Comment: Sry, don't know, but you could take a look at TvTrops under Void Powers. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PowerOfTheVoid

Answer (score 3):

The manga you're looking for is named [*Tanabata no Kumi*](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=19859). You're not mixing any mangas together, all what you've said is in that one.

Here is the synopsis:

> Basically, some humans have the ability to negate a sphere of reality, neatly removing it from existence. This gradually alters their appearance until they become a hideous alien, with a giant eye in their forehead.